# Finding the latest version of each row using Dask with Parquet files and partition_on?

Tags: pandas, dask

How can I make sure that am able to retain the latest version of a row (based on unique constraints) with Dask using Parquet files and `partition_on`?

The most basic use case is that I want to query a database for all rows `where updated_at > yesterday` and partition the data based on the `created_at_date` (meaning that there can be multiple dates which have been updated, and these files already exist most likely).

```
└───year=2019
    └───month=2019-01
            2019-01-01.parquet
            2019-01-02.parquet
```

So I want to be able to combine my new results from the latest query and the old results on disk, and then retain the latest version of each row (`id` column).

---

---

---

---

I currently have Airflow operators handling the following logic with Pandas and it achieves my goal. I was hoping to accomplish the same thing with Dask without so much custom code though:

1. Partition data based on specified columns and save files for each partition (common example would be using the date or month column to create files `2019-01-01.parquet` or `2019-12.parquet`

Example:

```
df_dict = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby(partition_columns)}
```

2. Loop through each partition and check if the file name exists. If there is already a file with the same name, read that file as a separate dataframe and concat the two dataframes

Example:

```
part = df_dict[partition]
part= pd.concat([part, existing], sort=False, ignore_index=True, axis='index')
```

3. Sort the dataframes and drop duplicates based on a list of specified columns (unique constraints sorted by `file_modified_timestamp` or `updated_at` columns typically to retain the latest version of each row)

Example:

```
part = part.sort_values([sort_columns], ascending=True).drop_duplicates(unique_constraints, keep='last')
```

The end result is that my partitioned file (`2019-01-01.parquet`) has now been updated with the latest values.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to use the existing parquet methods of a dataframe to do what you are after, but assuming your dask dataframe is reasonably partitioned, you could do the exact same set of steps within a `map_partitions` call. This means you pass the constituent pandas dataframes to the function, which acts on them. So long as the data in each partition is non-overlapping, you will do ok.

Comment: When you refer to partitions, do you mean the individual files or the partitions in memory (I know I can read a dataframe and repartition it in memory which then creates multiple files if I save it to disk)? If I read a directory of daily files from March 01 - March 31, are those 31 partitions which would then be processed by map_partitions?